# php fetch array expects resource, object given

Tags: php, mysql, loops, html-table, fetch

I want to loop out a table, but I'm giving it an object instead of resource. What is meant with resource? An array? What should I be fetching?

```
<?php 

    $db = new Db();
    $select = $db->conn->query("SELECT * FROM tbl_tweets");
    $rows = $select->num_rows;
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_tweets");
    $fetch = mysql_fetch_array($result);

    echo "<table>";
        for ($i=0; $i<$rows; $i++)
        {
        echo "<table><tr><td>".($fetch['tweet'])."</td></tr>";
        }
        echo "</table>";

    ?>
```

I've been looking at this for for long now, tried fetch_assoc also but I don't completely udnerstand the difference. Explanation on the difference is welcome.

Comment: Why are you calling `mysql_fetch_array` twice ?

Comment: *You* need to find out what `$db->conn->query()` does. It's unlikely that it returns a mysql resource handle.

Comment: Whatever `->query()` returns, it's obviously not meant to be used with `mysql_fetch_array`. You're using the wrong functions.

Comment: At what function should i be looking if I want to use fetch_array? Indeed, the $select dumps only a description of the array.

Comment: Try looking at the contents of the array generated by `get_object_vars($result)`.

Answer (score 0):

The first 3 lines of your code are not correct. if you plan to use the php mysql functions (I would recommend using PDO instead) you first need to establish a connection to your database using this code:

```
$link = mysql_connect('localhost', 'mysql_user', 'mysql_password');
if (!$link) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
echo 'Connected successfully';
}
```

then this line from your code:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM tbl_tweets");
```

then to loop through your results:

```
echo "<table>";
while($fetch= mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {

    echo "<tr><td>".$fetch['tweet']."</td></tr>";
}
echo "</table>";
```

Answer (score 0):

Solved it like this. The database connection is inside the Db class.

```
    $db = new Db();
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl_tweets";
    $allTweets = $db->conn->query($sql);

    while ($tweet = $allTweets->fetch_assoc()) 
    {
        echo $tweet['tweet'] . "</br>";
    }

    ?>
```